# How does this C program print a value 1 or 0?

Tags: c

This is is the simple program that I was writing in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  int i, j, k;
  i = 2; j = 3;

  k = i * j == 6;
  printf("%d", k);
}
```

so I know what this program is actually doing two values for the variable's are given here it does the calculation and then check;s the calculated value to the given condition.

Now here is what I am not getting When the program get executed it return's the value 1 when the given condition is satisfied and 0 if not, and i know that 1 stand's for true and o stand's for false but what i was thinking how doe's it do that i mean there is nothing in the program that tell' it to print 0 or 1 for the condition. Is it default in some C compilers to return that values or am i missing some point.

Comment: I see no declaration of variable `k`; this program will not compile.  Beyond that, you explained it yourself.  1 stands for true.  `6 == 6`, therefore the expression is true, which is represented as `1`.

Comment: that mean's it is default in the compiler to give the value on getting true or false values

Comment: Are you asking where it's defined that `true == 1` and `false == 0`? That is, why are those numerical values used for booleans?

Comment: yeah thank's just wanted to be sure

Comment: Side note:  when evaluating conditionals in C on integers eg. if(k), a non-zero value is interpreted as true and a zero value is interpreted as false.

Comment: @abelenky I've fixed his program so that it compiles and outputs like he says it does: http://ideone.com/rJNGPR

Comment: @Akash: So, what do you mean by "returns" here? The return value of `main`? Of the output of `printf`? Or something else?

Comment: @Paulpro that is the same i just didn't know to format that on this site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is nothing in the program that tells it to print 0 or 1 for the condition.

Yes there is, you print `k` and you assigned the result of the comparison to k. These are all equivalent (given that `i = 2` and `j = 3`):

```
k = i * j == 6;
k = (i * j == 6);
k = (6 == 6);
k = 1;
```

Then you print it:

```
printf("%d", k); // Prints 1
```

Comment: And what is the type of variable `k`?  Where is it declared?

Comment: @abelenky I'm assuming it's declared (as an integral type, probably safe to assume `int`) in the OP's actual program, which compiles and prints `1`.

Comment: so it is default in a compiler to print 1 or 0 in the output upon getting the condition executed

Comment: @Akash No, you're just printing the value of `k` and since `k == 1`, it prints `1`.

Comment: @Akash What would you expect the line `printf("%d", k);` to print?

Comment: but here k = i * j == 6 so k=6

Comment: @Akash No, if you had just written `k = i * j;` then `k` would be `6`, but you didn't, you wrote `k = (i * j == 6)`, so `k` becomes `1`. You are assigning the result of the comparison to `k`. The comparison is true, which is `1`, so you are assigning `1` to `k`.

Comment: and that is why i get a output 1 since the condition is true and 0 when it is false

Comment: @Akash, yes, compare [this](http://ideone.com/rJNGPR) and [this](http://ideone.com/tDRmJc). Both of which print the value of `k`.

Comment: @Akash This may help you understand too: http://ideone.com/YnLtyW `k = (6 == 6) + 2 + (4 <= 5);` assigns `4` to `k`, because both conditions are true, so that is the same as `k = 1 + 2 + 1;`

Answer (score 1):

As you said it yourself, logical expressions in C evaluate either to 0 (false) or to 1 (true).  That's exactly what "tells it" to put either `0` or `1` into your `k` variable, depending on whether the condition is satisfied.

Now, you seem to be talking about what your program "returns". I'm not sure what you mean by "returns" here. The program exit code perhaps? Your `main` function does not contain any `return` statements, which means that in C89/90 its return value will be unpredictable, while in C99 it will be guaranteed to return `0`. I suspect that you are using a C89/90 compiler that simply returns "garbage" from `main`, which purely accidentally happens to match the final value of `k`.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe he just means what it prints to stdout, when he says "returns".

Comment: i am using Code Block's and i think it is C99 compiler

Comment: @Akash: Well, if you are using a C99 compiler , the your main function (and your program) is guaranteed to *return* `0`. So, the question is then what you mean by "returns" in your original question. If you are referring to the output of `printf`, then you already know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In C, there is no true or false, just 1 and 0, or more precisely 0 and not 0.